# How should I finish this basement wall?

Tags: walls, basement-refinishing, concrete-block, basement-insulation

House built in 1970 in climate zone 3. These basement walls were apparently finished twice, the second time with drywall and originally with just wood against the concrete blocks with plaster as pictured (discovered after drywall came down). I'm pretty sure the concrete blocks are hollow/have no filler. I haven’t noticed any water on the walls since removing everything, but some of the wood that was directly against the west/NW walls had some mold, though hard to tell how long it’d been there since it was likely finished like that over a decade ago.

I saw [this method of covering the wall with insulation board](https://youtu.be/M3jwVa7MiEQ?si=y1J2UvRp331IoAxv&t=389) (use adhesive to create air gap between wall and insulation board) and figured I'd do that but not sure if the plaster ridges/channels are something I should deal with first somehow (chip away edges and be done? fill in for smoother plaster layer?).

Also I've seen about painting some kind of masonry waterproofing product as well but not sure if I should do that. I actually also had someone tell me not to have an air gap so I'm not sure what would be best. I assume either way make sure the insulation covers the entire block wall, including insulation board on top to the sill plate.

Probably not relevant but will then wood frame the walls and add some batt insulation before drywall again and use dricore r+ subloor inside the framed area.

[image: concrete block wall with plaster]

Comment: Climate zone isn't as important as your actual moisture situation. What's that like? Any hydrostatic seepage? Condensation? Please revise to add detail about that.

Comment: "How should I" -- You might want to websearch sites like This Old House, which have videos showing several approaches to insulating and finishing a wall. Which is best depends on a lot of factors, including your own experience in doing basic construction. Yes, you want to address any water leaks first before burying them.

Comment: I see a dried water mark on the floor, has that come from a spill or residue from cleaning the wall, or is it coming through the crack?

Comment: @Jasen depends on what you're talking about - that consistent darker line, maybe 6 inches from the wall, is from carpet glue because at some point a previous owner installed carpet.

Comment: I mean the wavy line

Comment: "not sure if the plaster ridges/channels are something I should deal with first somehow" - Only if you *really* want that, at most, 3/4" of the room back, where you're already going to lose ~6" from building a 2x4 wall, with 1" foam behind it, plus another inch away from the wall so you don't have to rip *every* stud to accommodate discrepancies. Plus 1/2" dry wall, 3/4" base shoe, and 1/2" quarter round. Anything that sits on the floor will be in a room that's *one foot smaller* then it is now.... *Should you?*